# How do I organize my notes in org-mode in terms of hierachy?

Tags: org-mode

In OneNote there're notebooks, each notebook contains tabs and each tab contains pages. What are those or alternatives to them in org-mode?

Comment: Org mode does not have a rigid hierarchy like that: you can set up your own mapping. E.g. notebook -> Org mode file; Tab -> Top-level headline; page -> Second-level headline. But that's just one possibility.

Comment: Orgmode orders things by means of headings and subheadings. It works very well for documents but less so for notes. I recommend you try out org-roam for a non-hierarchical approach to note organization. It really is magic when you have things set up.